# scrapy request does not work as in browser

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from foodie.fi.

To be able to scrape data for each region, I should select region and make search by product name.

When I'm selecting region from browser it makes request and return json as a response with 200 status.

But when I'm trying to make the same request from scrapy, it redirects me to wrong page (status 302).

Below is my scrapy code:

first request is to list regions.

second request is to select region (this one works wrong).

third request is scraping data from search product result in selected region.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from foodie.items import FOODIEItem

class FOODIESpider(Spider):
        name="foodie"
        allowed_domains = []



    def start_requests(self):
            yield Request(
                url="https://www.foodie.fi/store/list/region/Osuuskauppa%20Pee%C3%84ss%C3%A4",
                callback=self.select_store
                 )

        # Page parser
    def select_store(self, response):
                yield Request(
                    url="https://www.foodie.fi/store/select_store/41e9b2cb4ad9d81cc9ad5a640d78ed8f", 
                    callback=self.make_search
                )




    def make_search(self, response):
                yield Request(
                    url="https://www.foodie.fi/products/search/leip%C3%A4", 
                    callback=self.data_reader
                  )



    def data_reader(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        rows  = hxs.xpath("//*@id='page']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li")
        items = []
        for row in rows:
          name = row.xpath("./div[3]/div[1]/text()").extract()
          print name
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed if the data you want to scrape is generated by `javascript` ?

Do the following test: right click on the data, on the browser, and click inspect element. Then do "show page source" and ctrl+f the data you're looking for. If you can find it when inspecting but not on the page source it's probably invoked by `javascript`.

If that's the case I recommend using `selenium` along with `scrapy`. There are lots of examples in the internet, It's a browser driver, the easiest way to fetch that kind of data. you can use `selenium` + `PhantomJS` to use a headless browser.

Comment: I understand your recommendation, but it is not the case.

My issue:

the request in select_store function is being handled different ways when I'm doing it from scrapy vs browser.
Maybe the problem is coming from server side handling of requests: server may relay on cookies or client side data storage.

Reproduce:
Invoke request from browser (click on 4-th "Valitse myymälä" in right side):

https://www.foodie.fi/store/list/region/Helsingin%20Osuuskauppa%20Elanto

VS

the same request from scrapy.

Result: scrapy will redirect it to other page.
Expected: no redirect, server returns JSON data.

Comment: oh i'm sorry I couldn't help more. But still, if you're willing to factor cookies and all the parameters of the request, maybe it's just easier to use a headless browser such as PhantomJS. specially if performance isn't a conern. Good luck !

Comment: I have solved the issue, server was relaying on "User-Agent" header-field value.
Since, scrapy sets it's own "User-agent" value, server was rejecting it.

BTW, thanks for help.